# Selecting count in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, count

I got a SQL Server table with columns `ResolvedDate` and `ResolvedBy`.

Now I want to select those two columns and count their results, which I thought I'd implement like that:

```
_dataContext.Activities
    .Where(a => a.IsResolved && a.ResolvedBy == userId)
    .Select(a => new { a.ResolvedDate, ***COUNT*** });
```

As you can see, the Count-Part is missing.

I want to get every activity, that has been done in this ResolvedDate and count it.

How can I implement that?

Comment: so you want to group by the resolveddate then do a count

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
from a in dataContext.Activities
where a.IsResolved && a.ResolvedBy == userId
group a by a.ResolvedDate into g
select new {ResolvedOn=g.Key, NumberResolved= g.Count()}
```

Comment: This works great, thank you - just can't accept an answer yet :) Sadly this solution has one negative thing: 06.04.2012 12:00:00 Count 1 and 06.04.2012 12:00:01 Count 1 are ending up in two results. What do I have to do to group the entire day?

Comment: @SeToY change the third line to `group a by a.ResolvedDate.Date into g`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using EntityFramework 4. Thus the Typemember "Date" is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Comment: Resolved: group a by EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(a.ResolvedDate)

Answer (score 10):

If you're trying to count each item by date, you'd need to use `GroupBy`:

```
var countsByDate = _dateContext.Activities
                           .Where(a => a.IsResolved && a.ResolvedBy == userId)
                           .GroupBy(a => a.ResolvedDate)
                           .Select(g => new {ResolvedDate = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to group your data by ResolvedDate to get number of activities resolved every day.

```
var dates = from a in dataContext.Activities
            where a.IsResolved && a.ResolvedBy == userId
            group a by a.ResolvedDate into g
            select new { Date = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }
```

To group just by day (without hour, minutes, etc.) you can change the group statement:

```
var dates = from a in dataContext.Activities
            where a.IsResolved && a.ResolvedBy == userId
            group a by a.ResolvedDate.Date into g
            select new { Date = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }
```

Comment: "ResolvedDate" is nullable (when the activity is not resolved) and System.Nullable<DateTime> does not contain a definition for "Date"

Answer (score 3):

```
var dates = dataContext.Activities
    .Where(a => a.IsResolved && a.ResolvedBy == userId)
    .Select(a => a.ResolvedDate)
    .ToList();

var count = dates.Count;
```

If you only want to get the count, you can make it much faster by selecting the count alone:

```
var count = dataContext.Activities
    .Count(a => a.IsResolved && a.ResolvedBy == userId);
```

Comment: I think OP wants to group by the date and count the members of each group.

Comment: @SLaks: is `var count = dataContext.Activities
    .Count(a => a.IsResolved && a.ResolvedBy == userId);` equals to `select count(CoulmnName) from [TableName] Where (IsResolved=1) and (ResolvedBy=@UserID)`?