# Converting a stored procedure to a LINQ query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, stored-procedures

```
    public static IEnumerable<AppCache> GetTopRatedApps(string language,bool isinitialized)
    {
        List<AppCache> objApps = new List<AppCache>();

        objApps = GetAllApps(isinitialized,language).ToList();

        List<RatingCache> objRatings = new List<RatingCache>();

        objRatings = GetAllRatings();

           var query =
  from Apps in objApps
  join ratings in objRatings
      on Apps.AppId equals ratings.AppId where ratings.RatingGiven == 1 
  select new AppCache();

        return query;
    }
```

**Stored Procedure:**

```sql
select o.AppId, count(*) as ItemCount 
from App o 
inner join Rating od 
    on o.AppId = od.AppId 
where od.RatingGiven = 1
group by o.AppId
```

Can't figure out how to get the item count from the list.

Not: AppCache is equivalent to App

Comment: Does `group` help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx

Comment: also, look at some sample Groupings done in LINQ: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-Grouping-c62703ea

Comment: Here is a post which shows what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/10047966/2145211

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting count in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047942/selecting-count-in-linq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be the translation of your stored procedure. If you want to return something else, just modify the select method.

```
var query = from Apps in objApps
            join ratings in objRatings
              on Apps.AppId equals ratings.AppId
            where ratings.RatingGiven == 1 
            group Apps by Apps.AppId into g
            select new { AppId = g.AppId, ItemCount = g.Count() }
```